# Dynamic property names in flow typed object

Tags: javascript, syntax, flowtype

I'm slowly and surely working flowType into my code, but I'm struggling with one concept.

How do I specify the type of unknown, dynamically named properties of an object?

For example my user object might have an object containing organisations with unique keys.

How would I define this?

```
export type User = ?{
  currentOrg: string,
  displayName?: string,
  email: string,
  emailVerified: boolean,
  newAccount: boolean,
  organisations?: {
     UNKNOWNKEY?: string {
       orgData1: string,
       orgData2: string,
     }
  },
  uid: string,
  photoUrl?: string,
};
```

Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, it's not good practice to define your type as nullable in its definition. You probably don't want `null` to be a valid value for a `User` _everywhere_ that the type is used. It's much better to opt-in to making certain usages of `User` nullable. e.g.  `type Bug = { createdBy: User, assignedTo: ?User }`.

Comment: Great thanks a lot. Yes I noticed the same thing in retrospect and created two types, NullableUser and DefiniteUser which have either a ?User or User type. That way for most of my code I can use the DefiniteUser type.

Answer (score 31):

Flow has [specific syntax](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps) for objects that behave like maps:

```
{ [key: K]: V }
```

where `K` is they type of the keys and `V` is the type of the values.

Your full example would look like:

```
export type User = {
  currentOrg: string,
  displayName?: string,
  email: string,
  emailVerified: boolean,
  newAccount: boolean,
  organisations?: { [key: string]: string },
  uid: string,
  photoUrl?: string,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in TypeScript, you can use a name for the key and then pass the type of key:

```js
type User = {
  [key: string | number]: string;
};
```

In the FlowType, you can do it like TypeScript and also you can do it without a sample name:

```js
type User = {
  [string | number]: string,
};
```