# How Do You Define a Flowjs Type That Has Variable Keys?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

If I have a JS object that is structured something like the following, with keys that are variable date strings:

```js
availableTimes: {
  "2018-10-01": [...],
  "2018-10-02": [...],
  "2018-10-03": [...],
  "2018-10-04": [...]
}
```

What does it look like to express this as a generic Flow type? My mind initially thought this but I don't think it's correct.

```js
// @flow
export type AvailableTimes = {
  [string]: Array<AvailableMeetTime>
}
```

Comment: This might help { [key: string]: string } https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174498/dynamic-property-names-in-flow-typed-object

Comment: @VikramThakur That definitely worked! Thanks for posting that link! :)