# Is it possible to call function by name in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a code like below in the project

```
type ActionT = 'add' | 'put' | 'get'

function _dbRequest(action: ActionT) {
    ...
    const store: IDBObjectStore = _getStore(...)
    const request = store[action](...) // <- Error here 
    ...
}
```

It works fine but when I started to cover it with flow types I stuck with an error:

> an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing
> in  `IDBObjectStore` [1].Flow(InferError) indexeddb.js(54, 30): [1]
> `IDBObjectStore`

Please note [IDBObjectStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore) is kinda embedded type and I'd like not to override it if it's possible.
Are there any approaches to deal with it except of cast to `any`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic property names in flow typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174498/dynamic-property-names-in-flow-typed-object)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8483

Comment: @Yara_M Please edit `type ActionT` as valid `Flow Union Type`. No sense to use Logical OR inside type annotation. `type ActionT = 'add' | 'put' | 'get'`